# Cross origin security error although the iframe is on the same domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I get a security error in console when I click the button:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/" id="iframe"></iframe>
<input type="button" value="Color it!" id="button">
<script>
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'),
        button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.onclick = function () {
        iframe.src = 'linked-frame.html';
        iframe.contentDocument.body.style.background = 'red';
    };
</script>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4017788/Labs/cross-origin-security-error.html)**</kbd>

It shouldn't throw such an error as I change the `iframe` source in my function.

Comment: `Blocked a frame with origin "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.example.com".` -- how is that "same domain"?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the error message I get in Chrome. But it shouldn't throw such an error as I change the iframe source in my function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need to wait until the iframe loads after changing the src, before firing your function.

Try

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'),
button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function () {
  iframe.src = 'linked-frame.html';

  iframe.onload = function() {
    iframe.contentDocument.body.style.background = 'red';
  };

};
```

Example is here http://jsfiddle.net/vrTP9/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it gives the same error message if click on the link inside the red iframe: [Demo](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4017788/Labs/cross-origin-security-error2.html).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot simply hook into an iframe object, this is not allowed. You can add a `seamless` attribute to explicitely allow this behavior and then adapt your JavaScript to it:

```
// old syntax, can’t work
iframe.contentDocument.body.style.background
// new syntax, seamless attribute required:
frame.style.background = 'red';
```

Then it will work but [be aware of the browser support for `seamless` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: That doesn't help: `iframe` content body background color is different from the `iframe` element background color. To see what I mean compare `iframe.contentDocument.body.style.border = '1px solid red';` with `iframe.style.border = '1px solid red';`.

Comment: Oh, just had a look at it again. You have no CORS rules set on dl.dropboxusercontent.com (you can’t btw), so it isn’t allowed to access content this way. [You could use a tool like iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) for which you need access to both, your remotely embedded and your local server.